# Images not displying on web site but do display locally?

Tags: html, css, image, browser

I'm creating a web site and the site consists of a few images. Locally, everything displays correctly, but when I upload it to my server, some of the images are not displayed. None of the GIFs / Animated GIFs are displayed at all and some of the jpeg images are not displayed (while others are OK). The only images which don't appear to be effected are PNG, which display OK.

If I check FireBug and hover over the image link, I receive the message `Failed to load given URL`.

If I enter a direct URL link to the image on the server, the image is downloaded so it's definitely there.

Here's my CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top;
    background-image:url(../images/background2.gif);
}
```

I created another web site using the same code, but with a different background.gif image and everything displays correctly, so I'm not sure what else is different?

Also, I have tried deleting the images from the server and re-adding them, but still no luck.

Comment: Have you tried CTRL+F5, it may be that you CSS file is cached.

Comment: Yes and deleted my cache. I should mention that ive tried viewing it on firefox 19 and IE and its the same on both...

Comment: Sometimes when uploading images to a server, the file extensions get changed to upper case (has happened to me on more than one occasion). Check that the file extensions of the server hosted images are the same case as in your code

Comment: are you sure the images are in the correct place relative to your style sheet rather than the html page

Comment: Ive just checked the hosting space and they seem to be ok, in lowercase and match the code as far as I can see.

Comment: Yes the style sheet ref on my HTML pag is :
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> and the image sit in a folder called images. The structure on the server is web/  sitename/  then in there theres my index.html file and two folders called css and images

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in the full path in the url:

e.g. `background-image:url(http://www.your-site.com/images/background2.gif)`

-if that works, then check your paths and make sure the css url matches your directory structure.

Comment: Yeah tried that too, the weird thing is if I use the fully qualified link and put that straight into the browser that image is downloaded so its defiantly there and correct

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
background-image:url("../images/background2.gif");
```

Use:

```
background-image:url("/images/background2.gif");
```

Starting with "/" moves to the root directory and starts there

Starting with "../" moves one directory back and starts there

(also it's a good practice to always include quotes on paths)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's help, its turns out that this was a problem with some sort of bandwidth restriction on my work internet. If I viewed the site from anywhere else the images were all loaded..... I really though I was going mad for a while! Thanks again.